# How to select a polygon from a GeoDataFrame, while keeping the extent of the old GeoDataFrame

Tags: python, geopandas

I want to select a polygon from a GeoDataFrame and save it as new data. However, I want it to have the same extent as the old GeoDataFrame. Here is some code to create a GeoDataFrame

```
# create a geopandas dataframe from the polygons and attributes
# create a list of polygons
polygons = [Polygon([(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0)]),
            Polygon([(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (2, 1)]),
            Polygon([(2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3), (3, 2)])]

# create a pandas dataframe with some attributes
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3],
                   'name': ['polygon 1', 'polygon 2', 'polygon 3'],
                   'value': [10, 20, 30]})


# create a geopandas dataframe from the polygons and attributes
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=polygons)
```

plotting it looks like this

[image]

Then I select the polygon I want

```
#get shape 1
shape_1 = gdf.loc[gdf['id'] == 1]
```

plot it

[image]

What I want is for this square to be in the lower left corner, as if it was the original GeoDataFrame but minus polygon 2 and 3.